# Defining a variable inside Makefile cmd

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, gnu-make

Can we define a new variable inside a command of Makefile?

I'm writting a Makefile and I want to define a new variable just in one of the commands I use. Is there anyway? Or I'm missing something? I tried this script below but it doesn't work. Please help. Thank you

Makefile

```
build:
ifdef stack
 node_tag=$(shell echo $(tag)' | sed 's|$(stack)|&_node|')
endif
```

Comment: This question is not clear.  If you showed an example of what you really want to do we could help more.  For example, it's useless to just set a variable: clearly you want to USE that variable somewhere.  The only way we can tell you the right way to set the variable is if we know how you want to use it / what you want to use it for.  Do you want to define this variable for use in that same rule?  Some other rule?  Etc.

Comment: Yes, I need to reuse it in the same rule @MadScientist.

Comment: If you only need to use that variable in that one recipe, you probably shouldn't use a make variable at all.  Just use a shell variable.

Answer (score 2):

To define a variable inside a rule you need to use `eval`:

```
    $(eval myvar=$(shell echo hello))
    $(info myvar is ${myvar})
```

Comment: This isn't what I expected but really does solve my issue :D. Thank you.

Comment: This is not really true.  This sets a make variable, which will be in effect for the entire (remainder of) the makefile execution.  It doesn't set (as requested in the comments above) a variable only for the same rule.  Of course setting it for the entire rest of the makefile is a superset of setting it only for the same rule, so this will work but it does a lot more than requrested.

Comment: The variable can be unset if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the variable in the same rule then you want to set a *shell* variable and use that, rather than a make variable.  You can do this:

```
ifdef stack
tag_cmd = $$(echo '$(tag)' | sed 's|$(stack)|&_node|')
else
tag_cmd =
endif

build:
     node_tag=$(tag_cmd); echo $$node_tag
```

To reference a shell variable in the recipe you use `$$` to escape the dollar sign and you need to ensure the users of the variable are in the same recipe logical line.  This variable assignment exists only inside this recipe, in the shell that was invoked.  It will disappear once the recipe is over.